# A parametrization for $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as a revolution surface around $y$ axis

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I'm looking for a parametrization for $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as a revolution surface arround the $y$ axis.

I have tried $X(x,y)=\Big(\frac{\sin(y)\sin(x)}{x},x,\frac{\cos(y)\sin(x)}{x}\Big)$.

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sin[y] Sin[x]/x,x ,Cos[y] Sin[x]/x}, 
  {x, 0, 6*Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

But it does not make the surface it should be

```
Plot3D[Sin[Sqrt[x*x + y*y]]/Sqrt[x*x + y*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Is my parametrization right?
Can you give me some advice?
Any help thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps something like this. Just rotate the original function about the z-axis directly:

```
RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}].{x, 0, Sin[x]/x}
(* {x Cos[θ], x Sin[θ], Sin[x]/x} *)
```

and so:

```
ParametricPlot3D[RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}].{x, 0, Sin[x]/x}
 , {x, 0, 20}, {θ, 0, 2 π}
 , RegionFunction -> (-10 <= #1 <= 10 && -10 <= #2 <= 10 &)
 , PlotRange -> All
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]

Your original code seems to rotate around the x-axis:

```
ParametricPlot3D[RotationMatrix[θ, {1, 0, 0}].{x, 0, Sin[x]/x}
 , {x, 0, 10}, {θ, 0, 2 π}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

and rotating it about the y-axis is uninteresting. (Note that I have taken z to be "vertical".)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Sin[x]/x, {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Or to rotate around the *x*-axis: `evolutionPlot3D[Sin[x]/x, {x, 0, 6 Pi}, RevolutionAxis -> "X", 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 0.25, 0.25}]`